# Is it possible to use an existing node server for browser-sync?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser-sync

I have an existing node server running on a specific port. I would like to use it (if possible) for a browser-sync server.

I need it to be the same domain("localhost") and port because I'm embedding the browser-sync dev server on an iframe and I need to access the iframe's content but I'm getting a cross-origin error. I thought using a same domain would be an easier solution for this.

Is it possible to use an existing node/express server for browser-sync?